# run maven command from console same as eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, compilation, ant

I want to run a maven command from the console, to perform a task automation in the project.

But I want to run the maven command the same way ecplipse does when I run maven

Eclipse in the log does not show anything it does to run the command.
But the IDE has configured a settings.xml file that points to a local repository.
I want the execution of the command to be the same as what the IDE does, with the same variables.

The execution will be carried out from an ant task

Comment: What do you mean by "_perform a task automation in the project_"?

Answer (score 0):

If you perform *Right-Click* → *Run as* → *Maven build...* on a Maven project in Eclipse you create a *Run Configuration* in which you can set all the things you can set on the command line for `mvn ...`.